# How to create a data provider for use with Excel

Tags: .net, excel, dataprovider

Excel (2010) has functionality to create pivot tables from an external data source like from Access, From Web and other data sources like SQL server and ODBC. Suppose I have created a new database system called X and I want to create the functionality that Excel can connect to this X using a data provider (not an Excel Add-in). What do I develop and where do I start?

Comment: Question is constructive. There are only few valid answers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel can use any ADO.NET driver If I'm not mistaken. So all you need to do is to follow the following [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ksaf9z5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301611.aspx) is a more detailed description from MSDN Magazine.

You'll need to create an [OleDb driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yffccxb5.aspx) if Excel doesn't support ADO.NET drivers.